# Free/open interactive softwares/plugins for end-users' high-dimensional data visualization

Tags: visualization, data, dimensionality-reduction

Aside from questions about [How to visualize data of a multidimensional dataset (TIMIT)](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/how-to-visualize-data-of-a-multidimensional-dataset-timit), the [Purpose of visualizing high dimensional data?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/purpose-of-visualizing-high-dimensional-data) and [High-dimensional data: What are useful techniques to know?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/4942/high-dimensional-data-what-are-useful-techniques-to-know), I am looking at tools for high-dimensional data (numerical only) visualization, possibly embedding some dimension reduction techniques (Sammon maps, t-SNE), that could be used by end-users. I have found for instance:

- [HiSee](http://hisee.sourceforge.net/) (version 1.0.0, 2004-07-05),
- [GGobi](http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/) (version 2.1.10a, 2010-03-12),
- [Data Projector](https://github.com/datacratic/data-projector) (2014-07-15).

They do not seem to be heavily maintained. Are there more active or efficient developments to follow?

Comment: I am in a fix whether this belongs here or SoftwareRecs.  Looks like it's more at home here :)

Comment: I believe so, because of the interplay with dimension-reduction techniques. By the way, I feel that a tag for `high-dimensional data` is lacking here